# Objective C: Recognize if user is opening app for first time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I made an alert that randomly appears to remind the user to rate the app and then set a key BOOL to YES so that it doesn't pop up when a user hits rate. I need to initially set this to NO. Is there a function or variable that knows if its the first time a user is opening an app?

Comment: “I made an alert that randomly appears to remind the user to rate the app [and keeps popping up until the user does so]” I can guarantee that I'd rate your app one star for such an alert.

Comment: Not sure why the hostility. This is standard practice used by a TON of apps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using `NSUserDefaults` to store this `BOOL`, then when you ask the defaults for `boolForKey:`, it will automatically return `NO` if the `BOOL` does not exist in the defaults.

Comment: While this is exactly right for the specific situation, I think someone should point out `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`, the general way to specify baseline defaults. So here I am doing it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Set the BOOL firstTimeAppLaunch; firstTimeAppLaunch = TRUE; then `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:firstTimeAppLaunch forKey:@"firstTimeFlag"];`

then read it

```
BOOL tempFirstAppLaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstTimeFlag"];
    if(tempFirstTimeAppLaunch==TRUE)
    {
          //doSomething
        }
```

Comment: How does this ever indicate that it's **NOT** the first time launch? If you automatically set it to `YES`, then set the value in `standardUserDefaults`, then READ the value, you're going to get the same result each time!

Comment: For that you would set the value to NO within the method!                      BOOL tempFirstAppLaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstTimeFlag"];
    if(tempFirstTimeAppLaunch==TRUE)
    {
          //doSomething RIGHT HERE                                      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:@NO ForKey:@"firstTimeFlag"];     
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you save any kind of preferences, any configuration file, or anything else when the app is used, you can check for the existence of that data and assume first-use or a device restore and new install if that data isn't there at app start.

That probably sounds obvious. The point being that you can save some data to check for, a good example being a counter that indicates the number of times the app has launched (or re-awakened), ensuring that you don't ask for a rating until after at least the 3rd launch.